# Django Serialize Parent class

Tags: django, django-serializer

Given I have 2 models:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    userid = models.CharField()

class GoldMember(Member):
    parent_model = models.OneToOneField(Member, parent_link=True)
    date_start = models.DateField()

serializers.serialize("json", gold_member, fields=['name', 'userid', 'date_start']
        , use_natural_foreign_keys=True)
```

When I print the JSON, I only see the `date_start` field. However, I would like to have `name` and `userid`, which is from the parent class.

Without using `djangorestframework` because this is not used for any REST APIs, how can I get the JSON representation of `GoldMember` to be

```
{'date_start' = '2016-01-01', 'name' = 'John Doe', 'userid' = 'john.doe'}
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your serializers.py include:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from models import Member
from models import GoldMember


class MemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields = ('id','name','userid')


class GoldMemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    parent_model = MemberSerializer(many=False,read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = GoldMember
        fields =  ('id','parent_model','date_start')
```

and then somehwere in your views:

```
 serializer = GoldMemberSerializer(gold_member,many=False)
```

at this point you can print or return

```
 serializer.data
```

which should contain the JSON that you need.

Comment: It seems that I cannot run away from `rest_framework` so I'll just use it.